# Cumulative sum within a group

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following multi-index dataframe:

```
              A
H1   one      1
     two      0
     three    1
     four     2
H2   one      1
     two      4
```

I would like to compute on a new column the rolling **cumulative sum** within the group so that the output is:

```
              A   sum
H1   one      1     1
     two      0     1
     three    1     2
     four     2     4
H2   one      1     1   
     two      4     5
```

How can I do this in Pandas? (I am using the `master` branch BTW)

Comment: @DSM I just corrected the error. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all you need to do is use the `level` argument with `groupby` (as described in the [groupby with multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex) part of the tutorial):

```
>>> df["sum"] = df.groupby(level=0)["A"].cumsum()
>>> df
          A  sum

H1 one    1    1
   two    0    1
   three  1    2
   four   2    4
H2 one    1    1
   two    4    5
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this technically a `transform` or `apply` operation? I never quite understood the difference.

Comment: `apply` is the most general category of operation on a group, so lots of things fall under its umbrella.  What distinguishes transform operations is that they produce something indexed like the input, and that happens here, so I guess you could think of it as a transform.